# htaccess ReWriteCond ReWriteRule - redirect occurs even when URL includes nonsense characters

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, redirect

We've just finished a major re-structuring our website and I'm trying to write a set of redirect rules of varying specificity. The redirects are half working:

- They correctly re-route old URLs
- They incorrectly *also* allow and re-route URLs that include text *not* specified in the

ReWriteCond statements (when instead I would expect to see a "Not Found" error message displayed in the browser.)

Statements in the .htaccess file (located in the root of the web site) include:

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /company/company-history.html
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.technofrolics.com/about/index.html

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /press 
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.technofrolics.com/gallery/index.html
```

The above correctly executes the desired redirect
but also works when I enter the following after the domain name:

```
/youcanenteranytext/hereatall/anditstillworks/press
```

In other words, any text following the domain and preceding the conditional string seems to be allowed/ignored. Any advise on how to restrict the condition or rewrite rule to prevent this would be much appreciated!

Thanks, Margarita

Answer (score 0):

You need to including bounds in your regular expressions when you try to match against %{REQUEST_URI}, the `^` indicates the beginning of the match.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/company/company-history\.html
```

Will make it so requests for `/garbage/stuff/comapny/company-history.html` won't match. And likewise:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/press
```

Will make it so requests for `/youcanenteranytext/hereatall/anditstillworks/press` won't match. You can additionally employ the `$` in your regular expression to indicate the end of the match, so something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/press$
```

Will **ONLY** match requests for `/press` and not `/something/press` or `/press/somethingelse` or `/press/`.

Comment: Thanks @Jon  -syntax above doesn't currently work, but I've since learned I didn't completely understand our folder structure. Our domain's top level content is actually stored two subfolders beneath the domain's root folder and a parent .htaccess file in a higher directory is re-writing the 'base' - so when it reaches my .htacess file I think it's something like: technofrolics.com/technofrolics/technofrolics-dot-com . Not sure how to rewrite my 
RewriteBase / rule to deal with this and have your syntax work or otherwise handle it.